# Are "spinner" and "expandableListView" items present in Android Studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, expandablelistview

Good day to everyone! This is my first question :)

I am a beginner to Android Studio and I'm trying to write some code for an app. Surfing the web I've found videos showing interesting features about `spinner` and `expandableListView` that I'd like to use in my application. The problem is I can't find these items no matter what.
I have an android studio 3.5.3 version and the videos I saw showed versions 1.some.some and 2.some.some. Can anyone help me out with this, please?

Here an image about the palette I have in the android studio.
[image]

Comment: If you want to use lists in general you should use RecyclerView instead. You can still find now and then applications that use Spinners (they are under containers not widgets).

Comment: Thank you! Spinner is indeed under containers, my bad. I'll study the potential of RecyclerView. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use lists in general you should use RecyclerView instead. You can still find now and then applications that use Spinners (they are under containers not widgets). – DemoDemo